# How to print from a loop onto a single line

Tags: python, python-2.7, for-loop

The code:

```
for i in range(3):
    print '*'
```

prints:

```
*  
*  
*
```

Is there anyway to print it so it is all on one line with no spaces in between?

Comment: Does it?  It throws a `TypeError` for me.  Did you perhaps mean `for i in range(3):`?

Comment: @zondo I meant for it to be `for i in range(3):`

Comment: Then you can use the [edit] link.  It shows up just below the tags.  That isn't necessary this time, though, because I did it for you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A good chance to use the niceties of Python 3 with `from __future__`:

```
from __future__ import print_function

for x in range(3):
    print('*', end='')
```

Output:

```
***
```

Now you ar using the Python 3 `print()` function in Python 2:

> Docstring:

```
print(value, ..., sep=' ', end='\n', file=sys.stdout, flush=False)
```

> Prints the values to a stream, or to sys.stdout by default.
>   Optional keyword arguments:

```
file:  a file-like object (stream); defaults to the current sys.stdout.
sep:   string inserted between values, default a space.
end:   string appended after the last value, default a newline.
flush: whether to forcibly flush the stream.
```

You could also use:

```
print('*' * 3)
```

for the same output.

Answer (score 1):

Adding a comma after the print stops python from adding a newline, so you need the following. Also for i in 3 isnt valid syntax, maybe you were thinking of range(3)?

```
for i in range(3):
    print '*',
```

to have no spaces between them just add a backspace character to the start

```
for i in range(3):
    print '\b*',
```